# Scheduled emailing system in ASP.NET with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET with C# (VS 2008) to send mails with attachments using SMTP server and the `MailMessage` class.

Now I want to store this email message with attachment into a SQL Server 2008 database and later a Windows service will send mails by getting the mail contents from the database.

Could anyone provide information on storing emails with attachment into the database?

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556667/delaying-the-sending-of-emails-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy, really:

- have a basic `MailMessage` table with the basic columns like sender, recipient, subject, mail body, date to send the e-mail and so forth
- have a 1:n relationship to a `MailAttachment` table that stores the attachments for that message

The Windows service should then check the `MailMessage` table for mails that are due to be sent - and grab the information, create the .NET `MailMessage` object, and send it out. That service also needs to record any possible problems / error and update the `MailMessage` table with e.g.a status flag (0 = pending, 1 = sent successfully, -1 error occured) or something - so that you can monitor your mail sending service.

The problems start when you realize that sending an e-mail isn't that simple......

- what if you have multiple recipients?
- do you want to send only plain text, or HTML e-mails?

Those are things you need to consider before building your tables.

Comment: I am new in .net development;Can I get windows service that you are talking about.

Comment: @Frank: open Visual Studio > New Project > Windows Service and then start coding .....

Comment: but how i can start i don't know anything.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to store the attachment itself in the database. You can save the location as nvarchar: "~/attachmentFolder/attachment.fileEXT"
Then retrieve attachment with Server.MapPath(tableRow.ColumnName)