# Sending emails at certain time

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I would like to send email using SMTP Server, but in the certain time.
Is there possibility to setup some option so it will be in the queue on SMTP Server until specific time and date?

Idea is to avoid using Windows Service or extra table in DB

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("no-reply@tttt.com", "xxxx@gmail.com");
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Subject = "Publishing Notification";
message.Body = "tes";
message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("xxxx", Int32.Parse("25"));
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delaying the sending of emails in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556667/delaying-the-sending-of-emails-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ok, but my client would like to avoid this kind of setup. They are wondering if there is possibility to do it without WIndows Service or additional tables in DB.

Comment: C# isn't capable of what you suggest in your question. You'll have to rely on the server to queue your delay or some 3rd party software (like outlook).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, both the `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` instances should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: And while we are talking about code why are you `Int.Parse()ing` the SMTP port, you could just write a 25 in. Or skip it if you are using the default port.

Comment: Example of code is just example and prof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

Making something execute at a given time is an easy problem presuming you've got a process to host it. But it seems like your client is refusing to get there. Here are two ways to approach this without:

- Use Sql Server Jobs to execute a database mail task. This could be a very easy on-ramp depending on where the data is coming from.
- Use a scheduled task to execute a command line program. Or use the Sql Job Manager to execute the program for that matter if getting a sql job in there is easier than standing up a scheduled task.

Quartz.NET is a great library and we use it a lot but you still need a constantly running service to execute scheduled tasks there. So, if you can piggyback this on your web app Quartz would work but if not then you'd be looking at writing a service. And from there you'd be better off just making it a scheduled task since there is no reason for this to be a service other than scheduling.